# Can't connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

VB.NET Express 2010.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    connection = New MySqlConnection()

    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=example.com; Uid=***; Pwd=***; Database=***;"

    Try
        connection.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
        connection.Close()
    Catch mysql_error As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & mysql_error.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have imported MySql.Data.MySqlClient too:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

But when I click the button, the whole application just freezes.

I have added the reference to MySql.Data.dll. The path:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Data.dll
```

Such file was installed from an installer downloaded from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Why is that?

Comment: Where does it freeze in the applications execution?  My bet is that is is trying to make a connection to the server and it is taking longer than expected and not timing out. Set a break point on MessageBox.Show and see if it gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed the `server` parameter of the connection string to point to your local installation, this would explain why it is hung.